# Trying to understand some simple recursive C code

Tags: c

Can somebody tell me how the flow is going on after the output statement "value of x before is 8" ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sum(int x)
{
    if(x==9)
        return;

    printf("\n value of x before is %d",x);

    /* recursive calling of Sum() function */

    sum(x+1);

    printf("\nvalue of x after is %d",x);
}

int main()
{    
    sum(2);
}
```

output:

```
value of x before is 2
value of x before is 3
value of x before is 4
value of x before is 5
value of x before is 6
value of x before is 7
value of x before is 8
value of x after is 8
value of x after is 7
value of x after is 6
value of x after is 5
value of x after is 4
value of x after is 3
value of x after is 2
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a recursive function the statements following the recursive call are pushed to the stack.

So the statement after `sum(x+1)` is the `printf()` which is pushed to the stack and retrieved when you return from the function.

When you call `sum(2+1)`

```
printf("\nvalue of x after is %d",x);/* x =2 */
```

is pushed to the stack. So the last push will be `printf()` with `x=8`

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `sum(i)` is replaced by

```
print value of x before is i
call sum(i + 1)
print value of x after is i
```

which is then replaced by

```
print value of x before is i

print value of x before is i + 1
call sum(i + 2)
print value of x after is i + 1

print value of x after is i

. . .
```

until i reaches the value 8. With the help of print statements, it is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void p(int x) {
    while(x--) putchar(' ');
}

void sum(int x)
{
    if(x==9)
        return;

    p(x); printf("value of x before is %d\n",x);

    /* recursive calling of Sum() function */

    sum(x+1);

    p(x); printf("value of x after is %d\n",x);
}

int main()
{    
    sum(2);
}
```

Will output this:

```
$ ./rec
  value of x before is 2
   value of x before is 3
    value of x before is 4
     value of x before is 5
      value of x before is 6
       value of x before is 7
        value of x before is 8
        value of x after is 8
       value of x after is 7
      value of x after is 6
     value of x after is 5
    value of x after is 4
   value of x after is 3
  value of x after is 2
```

What this means is that the function calls are behaving like the following:

```
 sum(2)
 2  is 2 == 9? NO
 2  print before
 2  sum(3)
 2  3   is 3 == 9? NO
 2  3   print before
 2  3   sum(4)
 2  3   4   is 4 == 9? NO
 2  3   4   print before
 2  3   4   sum(5)
 2  3   4   5   is 5 == 9? NO
 2  3   4   5   print before
 2  3   4   5   sum(6)
 2  3   4   5   6   is 6 == 9 ? NO
 2  3   4   5   6   print before
 2  3   4   5   6   sum(7)
 2  3   4   5   6   7   is 7 == 9 ? NO
 2  3   4   5   6   7   print before
 2  3   4   5   6   7   sum(8) 
 2  3   4   5   6   7   8       is 8 == 9 NO
 2  3   4   5   6   7   8       print before
 2  3   4   5   6   7   8       sum(9)
 2  3   4   5   6   7   8       9   is 9 == 9? YES 
 2  3   4   5   6   7   8       9   RETURN  
 2  3   4   5   6   7   print after
 2  3   4   5   6   7   RETURN
 2  3   4   5   6   print after
 2  3   4   5   6   RETURN
 2  3   4   5   print after
 2  3   4   5   RETURN
 2  3   4   print after
 2  3   4   RETURN
 2  3   print after
 2  3   RETURN
 2  print after
 2  RETURN

 main continues here
```

The leading number indicate "which" `sum()` function you're. It's the value of `x` inside that function.

Furthermore, note that the function with value 3 is "inside" the function with value 2. And function with value 4 is "inside" the function with value 3.

I say inside because the [stack frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) of subsequent function calls lives within the stack frame of the caller function. However, this **does not mean that recursive called functions can access their caller's data**. To do that, you must use pointers like any other function call.